# Insufficient Privileges error while installing beta package

Tags: managed-package, custom-object

I recently had the following error while trying to install a beta managed package in a Developer Organization:

> **Insufficient Privileges**
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

This error would occur immediately after following the installation link for the beta package (https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=xxx).

There was no log, no error code, no gack, just this error. A quick Google search returns nothing, as I was logged as an administrator user, with all the permissions required to install a managed package.

Contacting Salesforce premier support gives us nothing, as they couldn't find any log either. The issue could be found in the organization that **uploaded** the beta package. However, in this organization, the package was marked as successfully uploaded.

So, in my case, this was due to a new **custom object** that I just added to the package before upload. This custom object was named `List__c` (without namespace).

Removing this object from the package solved the issue. **Renaming** it to `ZList__c` solved the issue too!

I can only guess that this is a Salesforce very particular issue.

#### Questions

- Have you already seen such an error while trying to install a beta managed package?
- Any idea why renaming this custom object would solve the issue?

Please note that creating an **unmanaged** package with a `List__c` custom object doesn't seem to reproduce the error.

Thanks,
Mickael.

Comment: Does the custom object exhaust any limits in the target org (too many lookups? toal # tabs > 25? etc)? Is there any post-install script in the package that might trigger it? Any weird stuff about being licensed to use managed package X before certain stuff can run on this object? Anything "unusual for Dev Edition?" (Knowledge Base, CTI, Live Agent, Salesforce to Salesforce... etc. special features / licenses)

Comment: No, as far as I know the custom object did not exhaust any of the limits you quoted. This was a brand new custom object introduced in the package.xml with very few fields (5) all text, single-select list or number.

Comment: Depending on how much time are you willing to spend on it you might try to inspect object's XML definition (in Eclipse for example). Any chance it was being deployed with something Chatter-related and it wasn't enabled in target org? I'm afraid that if support had no idea and there was no internal error we can't help much... 1 more idea: trust.salesforce.com - check for outages & maintenance around that time?